# Seafarers of Catan fog scenario question

Tags: catan, catan-seafarers

Scenario: I am placing my ships out into the unknown and at the end of my "road" I decide to build a settlement. When the new hex is flipped it is a water tile and now a settlement cannot be built. Must I replace it with a boat and play the appropriate cards instead?

Comment: I think you should flip a tile first.

Answer (score 7):

You should reveal the hex tile when you first build a ship that reaches it; you don't wait until you are building a settlement.

From [the rules](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?Seafarers_rv_Rules_091907.pdf):

> When a ship (or a road) is connected to an unexplored
>   area, a new tile will be discovered! If you place a ship or road
>   that connects to the intersection of an unexplored hex, you
>   must immediately draw the top tile from the pile and place it
>   face up in the empty space.